# SprightlySoft S3 Sync last version?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, amazon-s3

I want to download [SprightlySoft S3Sync](http://aws.amazon.com/code/4253), but it seems its down or that company was buy. Does someone has the last version? Can you please upload it, and send me url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the webpage is back... I could download myself